# Road Graph Plugin missing in Qgis 2.8.3

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.8

Road Graph Qgis plugin is missing in the official repository, at least, I am not be able to find it.

Is it replaced for Network tool in Vector menu? Is there another easy way to have the shortest path or Service Area? I know there is PgRouting, but I can not use it because I need the tool for a beginner training and I think PgRouting is too difficult in this level of training.

Edit:

I am afraid the plugin is not available in my computer, nor in others computers I have tasted.[image]

I have looked for it in [the project official repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/?page=29&&) and the plugin is not shown.

Could anybody answer why this is happening?

Comment: you should really edit your question as it is not clear if you're are looking for missing Road Graph plugin itself (one problem) or for it's replacement (another).

Comment: I am looking for a missing Road Graph plugin but If there is another solution or another plugin that can help me in the operations I need to solved that be fine too.

Answer (score 3):

Road Graph plugin is still there both in 2.8.3 and 2.12.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try another method of accessing the **Road Graph** plugin which is from the toolbar:

*View > Panels > Shortest Path*

For me (using QGIS 2.12.0-Lyon), it shows up underneath the *Layers Panel*:

[image: Road Graph]

As it is a core plugin, it *should* already come installed with QGIS.

Comment: Thank you very much, Joseph. I finally have found in the View > Panels > Shortest Path. Sorry for the wrong way to use the forum, next time I will try to do it better.

Comment: @NataliaBernal - Awesome, glad you found it! And no need to apologise, everyone makes mistakes when doing something for the first time :). You could also take a quick [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

It's a core plugin, so, it's already installed.
You just need to look for it using the translated name....
Your QGIS is in Spanish, use the spanish translation of "Shortest" to find it.